# django: generic class view + POST = HTTP 405 (Method not allowed)

Tags: python, django, http, http-status-code-405

Recently I've started converting some of the view functions to Generic Views. 
Converting the function which was expected to handle POST request (via AJAX form) results in "405 Method not allowed" HTTP exception.
I'm sure is **not** about CSRF: Ajax sends valid token, changing the generic view back to view function (in the test case, they're essentially the same) fixes the problem, and - lastly - for testing purposes, I've disabled CSRF middleware. 
Did anyone experienced similar problems?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose you are using class-based views.  If so then you need to define `post` method in your view or use mixin which does it (`django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView` for example).  If you want to fully understand why this is necessary then look at [`dispatch`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/base.py#L56) method of `django.views.generic.base.View`.

Comment: I didn't end my url with slash at the end. That was my issue.