# Django upload multiple images with one input Method Not Allowed (POST): /images/

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

HI I have just built an HTML-form in which the user can upload multiple images but I am getting `Method Not Allowed (POST): /images/` all the time. In the `image_list.html` the images should be shown.
Thanks for your help

models.py

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
```

forms.py

```
class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageModel
        fields = ['images']
        widgets = {
            'images': FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

views.py

```
class ImageFormView(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'image_form.html'
    form_class = ImageForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Save the images to the database
        form.save()
        # Redirect to the image list view
        return redirect('image_list')
    
    
class ImageListView(ListView):
    model = ImageModel
    template_name = 'image_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'images'
```

image_form.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit
</form>
```

image_list.html

```
{% load static %}
{% for image in images %}
<img src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('images/', views.ImageFormView.as_view(), name='image_form'),
    path('', views.ImageListView.as_view(), name='image_list'),
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django: generic class view + POST = HTTP 405 (Method not allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563482/django-generic-class-view-post-http-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: Now I know where the problem is. I need to make sure that it is a ```post``` request inside the class-based-view. [The documentation for that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/) says that I should name my function ```post``` right? Then I am getting ```AttributeError at /images/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'save'``` this error. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to close button tag at HTML form

```html
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```